# Get offset and length of a subset of a WAT archive from Common Crawl index server

Tags: common-crawl

I would like to download a subset of a WAT archive segment from Amazon S3.

**Background:**

Searching the Common Crawl index at http://index.commoncrawl.org yields results with information about the location of WARC files on AWS S3. For example, searching for [url=www.celebuzz.com/2017-01-04/*&output=json](http://index.commoncrawl.org/CC-MAIN-2017-34-index?url=www.celebuzz.com%2F2017-01-04%2F*&output=json) yields JSON-formatted results, one of which is

`{
   "urlkey":"com,celebuzz)/2017-01-04/watch-james-corden-george-michael-tribute",
   ...
   "filename":"crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2017-34/segments/1502886104631.25/warc/CC-MAIN-20170818082911-20170818102911-00023.warc.gz",
   ...
   "offset":"504411150",
   "length":"14169",
   ...
}`

The `filename` entry indicates which archive segment contains the WARC file for this particular page. This archive file is huge; but fortunately the entry also contains `offset` and `length` fields, which can be used to request the range of bytes containing the relevant subset of the archive segment (see, e.g., [lines 22-30 in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Smerity/56bc6f21a8adec920ebf)).

**My question:**

Given the location of a WARC file segment, I know how to construct the name of the corresponding WAT archive segment (see, e.g., [this tutorial](https://dmorgan.info/posts/common-crawl-python/)). I only need a subset of the WAT file, so I would like to request a range of bytes. But how do I find the corresponding offset and length for the WAT archive segment?

I have checked the [API documentation](https://github.com/ikreymer/pywb/wiki/CDX-Server-API) for the Common Crawl index server, and it isn't clear to me that this is even possible. But in case it is, I'm posting this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Common Crawl index does not contain offsets into WAT and WET files. So, the only way is to search the whole WAT/WET file for the desired record/URL. Eventually, it would be possible to estimate the offset because the record order in WARC and WAT/WET files is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is what I suspected.

Comment: There's also a [github thread](https://github.com/commoncrawl/commoncrawl/issues/11#issuecomment-224655532) about this, without a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

After many trial and error I had managed to get a range from a warc file in python and boto3 the following way:

```
# You have this form the index
offset, length, filename = 2161478, 12350, "crawl-data/[...].warc.gz"

import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config

# Boto3 anonymous login to common crawl
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))

# Count the range
offset_end = offset + length - 1
byte_range = 'bytes={offset}-{end}'.format(offset=2161478, end=offset_end)
gzipped_text = s3.get_object(Bucket='commoncrawl', Key=filename, Range=byte_range)['Body'].read()

# The requested file in GZIP
with open("file.gz", 'w') as f:
  f.write(gzipped_text)
```

The rest is optimisation... Hope it helps! :)

Comment: This is useful for getting the offset of a WARC archive, but my original question was about doing the same for a WAT file...

Comment: Consider using [this Python tool](https://github.com/lxucs/commoncrawl-warc-retrieval) or the [Java WARCReaderFactory.get](https://github.com/iipc/webarchive-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/archive/io/warc/WARCReaderFactory.java) version.